# Using vmatrix inside align, with other equations

Tags: amsmath

What I would like to do is to solve a system of linear equations with three variables (let them $d$, $e$, and $f$) with Cramer's rule. I have done `\usepackage{amsmath}`.
At least I can compile this:

```latex
\begin{align}
        \left|\mathbf{\Delta}\right|
        =&
        \begin{vmatrix}
                0 & 1 & 1\\
                2 & -4&0 \\
                1 &  0&-2
        \end{vmatrix}
        =0+0+0-(-4)-(-4)-0
        =8
\end{align}
```

But I cannot:

```latex
\begin{align}
        \left|\mathbf{\Delta}\right|
        =&
        \begin{vmatrix}
                0 & 1 & 1\\
                2 & -4&0 \\
                1 &  0&-2
        \end{vmatrix}
        =0+0+0-(-4)-(-4)-0
        =8
        \\

        d
        =&
                hello
```

The first error message is this:

```
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(./main.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Runaway argument?
 =0+0+0-(-4)-(-4)-0 =8 \\
! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.66

?
```

I was about to follow three equations that shows what $d$, $e$ and $f$ are.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: All-blank lines are not alllowed inside equations. Remove the blank line before `d` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Two additional comments: (a) If you want correct spacing around the alignment points, you should write `&=`, not `=&`. (b) There is no good reason for writing `\left|\mathbf{\Delta}\right|` -- unless you're a fan of code clutter. Do please write `|\mathbf{\Delta}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for commenting me to advise! They worked!

```latex
\begin{align}
        |\mathbf{\Delta}| % Not really good to use \left| and \right|
        &= % =& does not look good
        \begin{vmatrix}
                0 & 1 & 1\\
                2 & -4&0 \\
                1 &  0&-2
        \end{vmatrix}
        =0+0+0-(-4)-(-4)-0
        =8
        \\
% no blank line!
        d
        &= % not =&
                hello
\end{align}
```